# How to access changes made to your branch locally git

Tags: git

My colleague made changes to my branch and forgot to commit, and left for holiday. Say my branch name is `ImplementA` is it possible to know what was changed or done using a `git` command? on `implementA` in their local machine ? the branch is already pushed for review.

Comment: Are you and your colleague working on the same machine?

Comment: Not the same machine, different machine.

Comment: If the colleague hasn't committed, then the changes do not exist on any branch yet. They exist locally only in the working directory. Is it on a different machine or is it a shared computer?

Comment: If the colleague didn't make any commits, then how can the branch have been pushed for review?

Comment: @Maria If you are sure the branch was pushed for review, then the right question would be "How do I pull changes from a remote repository?"

Comment: Does someone have access to your colleague's machine where the changes were made before they return from holiday? If not, you'll just have to wait to get those changes, or redo them yourselves. Also, the last sentence doesn't make sense. Either your colleague *did* commit and pushed the commit, or your colleague *did not* commit in which case whatever was pushed isn't going to help you.

Answer (score -1):

You can run `git diff` to determine the changes on the local branch.

See here: [Git Diff](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-diff#:%7E:text=git%20diff%20is%20a%20multi,%2C%20branches%2C%20files%20and%20more.&text=The%20git%20diff%20command%20is,state%20of%20a%20Git%20repo.)

However, these are just the changes on **your** local branch, that would not include changes your colleague made to his local branch. Without access to his machine I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: Ah, this would have to be on the machine where the changes were made. This will not work on YOUR machine.